# Using a java XmlType annotated object on the client side to access a database on the server side with a web service

Tags: java, database, web-services, soap, webmethod

I am developing a java web service as well as a java client for the service and I am wondering if my design is even possible within the constraints of a SOAP-based, document style web service.  On the server side I have a database which I am using a utility class to connect to and a couple other database "handler" classes that manipulate the database.  My web service has WebMethods that return the handler classes.  Each of the handler classes is annotated with the @XmlType annotation so that they can be bound to XML types.  My question is if my client calls one of the webmethods and gets one of the database handler can I in turn manipulate the database on the server side through the methods of the handler (which are not annotated @WebMethod).  Is something like this possible with SOAP-based web services?

I have example code below.

Here is the functionality of my utility class.

```
    public class DBUtil {
        public static getConnection() {
            return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        }
    }
```

Here is an example of one of my database handlers.

```
    @XmlType
    public class Handler1 {

        public LinkedList<String> listDatabases() {
            Connection con = DBUtil.getConnection();
            LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
            //use con to query database and fill list with know database names
            return list;
        }

        public LinkedList<UserData> listUser(String database) {
            //UserData is a user defined type that store information about user names
            //and their privileges

            Connection con = DBUtil.getConnection();
            //query database and fill a LinkedList list with one UserData object
            //for each database user
            return list;
        }
    }
```

My other handler classes contain similar methods for querying and modifying tables.

Below is my web service.

```
@WebService()
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT)
public class WSDatabaseImp implements WSDatabase {

    //WSDatabase is my SEI

    public WSDatabaseImp() {}

    @WebMethod
    public Handler1 getHandler1() {
        return new Handler1();
    }
    //more get HandlerX methods
}
```

What I want to do is use Handler1 and such in my client to manipulate the database. The code below demonstrates what I want to do and assumes that I have run run wsimport that generate the artifacts.

```
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WSDatabaseImpService service = new WSDatabaseImpService();
        WSDatabaseImp port = service.getWSDatabaseImpPort();
        Handler1 h = service.getHandler1();
        LinkedList<String> list = h.listDatabases();
        for(String s: list)
            System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Is this design possible?  Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO! While your question is well formatted (+1 for that) some people may consider this is [too broad to this site](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you don't have a particular error with your design ***but*** you're trying to get some help related to design desitions then you might consider post what are your choices, pros and cons you can see on these ones, etc.

Comment: Okay, thanks dic19 I will keep that in mind in the future.  I found out that the best way to implement this web service was to simply call the Handler methods through the SEI rather than pass these objects through the @WebMethods.